# Gulp: concatenate a file to each separate sass process

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-concat

I wrote a gulp task to process all `scss` files in one folder into separate `css` files.

```
gulp.task('process', function () {
  gulp.src(['./base.scss', './layout/*.scss'])
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

Now I want to concatenate one file (`base.scss`) to each `scss` process; how can I do this?

Comment: So you want to concatenate base.scss to each .scss file before the sass() pipe ?

Comment: @Mark exactly..

Comment: @FaridRn - just wondering why you were doing this? My generated css is currently v big and trying to find out what scss files are adding the most weight. I was thinking of creating a css from each scss files and then seeing the size. Tried the above and below with little joy.

Comment: @v3nt I was trying to create RTL version of a template that had too many css files; each one of these files was being loaded based on the plugins used in pages. in other words I wanted to create RTL-ized version of each file with `-rtl` postfix and place them alongside with their original files.
I'm glad to hear that my question helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you but I didn't test it.  [Gulp-foreach](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-foreach) is good for you, it will treat each file from gulp.src as its own stream which you can manipulate separately.  The code below then appends your base.scss to each stream, then concatenates them and then they go through the sass pipe.

```
var foreach = require('gulp-foreach');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var addsrc = require('gulp-add-src');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('./layout/*.scss')
      // treats each file in gulp.src as a separate stream
    .pipe(foreach(function (stream, file) {
      return stream
         // append or prepend
       .pipe(addsrc.append('./base.scss'))
        //  you do have access to the 'file' parameter here if you need to rename
       .pipe(sass())
       .pipe(concat(path.basename(file.path)))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    }));
});
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I did it with `gulp-foreach` but used `dest` inside `foreach` and not on `src`'s pipe and it worked, and edited your answer so I can mark it as accepted, hoping that you're not mad at me!